# Typescript TypeError: this.setSelection is not a function

Tags: typescript, angular

I am building an Ionic2 application wherein I am using Google maps API where I draw a polygon, should be able to delete the shape etc.

However, I get `TypeError: this.setSelection is not a function` error. I am new to typescript and do not know how to fix it.

**My component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/start/start.html'
})

export class StartPage {

  selectedShape: any;

  constructor( private navController : NavController, private platform : Platform) {

    this.initializeMap();

  }

  clearSelection = (): void => {

    if(this.selectedShape) {
      this.selectedShape.setEditable(false);
      this.selectedShape = null;
    }
  }

  setSelection = (shape): void => {

    console.log("Inside function")

    this.clearSelection();
    this.selectedShape = shape;
    shape.setEditable(true);
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.selectedShape.getPath(), 'set_at', this.calcar);
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.selectedShape.getPath(), 'insert_at', this.calcar);
  }

  calcar() {

    console.log(this.selectedShape)

    var area = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(this.selectedShape.getPath());
    document.getElementById("area").innerHTML = "Area =" + area.toFixed(2);
  }

  deleteSelectedShape() {
    if (this.selectedShape) {
      this.selectedShape.setMap(null);
    }
  }

  initializeMap() {

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      var minZoomLevel = 15;

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        zoom: minZoomLevel,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.5200, 13.4050),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        zoomControl: true    
      });

      var polyOptions = {
        strokeWeight: 0,
        fillOpacity: 0.45,
        editable: true
      };

      let drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
        polygonOptions: polyOptions,
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', (e) => {

      if (e.type != google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
      // Switch back to non-drawing mode after drawing a shape.
      drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);

      // Add an event listener that selects the newly-drawn shape when the user
      // mouses down on it.
      var newShape = e.overlay;
      newShape.type = e.type;

      google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', ()=> {

        this.setSelection(newShape);

      });

      var area = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(newShape.getPath());
      document.getElementById("area").innerHTML = "Area =" + area.toFixed(2);

      () => {this.setSelection(newShape);}
    }
  });

      google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'drawingmode_changed', ()=>{this.clearSelection;});
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click',  ()=>{this.clearSelection;});
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('delete-button'), 'click',  ()=>{this.deleteSelectedShape;});

    });

  }

}
```

setSelection, clearSelection, deleteSelection calcar I can not invoke through my intializeMap() function using this.setSelection. Why? How to fix it?

**UPDATE:**
Code is updated as per suggestions in the answers. It still throws error in calcar saying `can not read property getPath() of undefined`

Answer (score 1):

use arrow function

```
google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', ()=> {
    this.setSelection(newShape);
});
```

Comment: This still did not solve the error. I changed the last three lines as well clearSelection and deleteSelection with similar code. It is throwing this error at 5th line from bottom which is again this.setSelection(newShape);

Comment: there is another one you need to change, `google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
`

Comment: in fact, if you can, try to use arrow function as default.

Comment: I updated the question with latest question, however it still doesn't function as expected. It is throwing an error in calcar() that getPath() of undefined. I tried to make it arrow function as well, but there were compilation errors.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

```
// issue
google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function() {
   this.setSelection(newShape);
});
```

`this` inside the function is referring to the function context and not your class.

You can fix it by using an arrow instead

```
// fix
google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', () => {
   this.setSelection(newShape);
});
```

Then it will compile into something like this:

```
// compiled
var _this = this;
google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function () {
    _this.setSelection(newShape);
});
```

Which now will be referring to the object you intended to use.

[See more about arrow functions on MDN, read about Lexical this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/hk82v0zp/2/ the original fiddle I referred to. It did not solve the error. I changed the last three lines as well to have similar declaration. It could be possible that I am doing something totally wrong.